# ios UIScrollView auto scroll to end in timeline

Tags: ios

I hava a UIScrollView, it's contentSize.width = Width
and I want to auto scroll ContentOffset from .zero to end in timeline.

here is my code, but it doesn't work

```swift
  
    fileprivate func startTimer() {
 
        if let `timer` = timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollRatingView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer?.fire()
        
    }
    
    @objc fileprivate func scrollRatingView() {
        
        var offsetX = ratingContainer.contentOffset.x

        offsetX += ratingContainer.contentSize.width / CGFloat(totalTime) * 100

        self.ratingContainer.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offsetX, y: 0), animated: true)
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `UIView.animate` will work here... Just set `withDuration` for how long you want it to be scrolling. Might need to change the `contentOffset.x` value to suit your exact needs.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: someTime) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentSize.width 
    scrollView.layoutIfNeeded() // This must be called to animate
}
```